# Eclipse not running Java Code

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, palindrome

Am really new to Java, started to study it on my own.... I downloaded netbeans and Eclipse and the two gave me the same result.. they don't run the code (stuck on running) neither let me debug it - Eclipse debugger and Netbeans - was not responding :? I don't whats wrong.. and I got no clue as I can't debug..

Here's my code: am tryin to check for palindrome:

```
package ClassQueue;

class Stack {

    private Object[] Stack_Array = null;
    public int top = 0;

    public Stack(int size) {
        top = 0;
        Stack_Array = new Object[size];
    }

    public Stack() {
        this(100);
    }

    protected void finalizer() {
        Stack_Array = null;
    }

    final public boolean empty() {
        return top == 0;
    }

    final public boolean full() {
        return top == Stack_Array.length;
    }

    public void push(Object token) {
        if (!full()) {
            Stack_Array[top] = token;
            top++;
        }
    }

    public Object pop() {
        Object Value_return = -999;
        if (!empty()) {
            Value_return = Stack_Array[top];
            top--;
        }
        return Value_return;
    }
}//end of Class_Stack

class Queue {

    private Object[] Queue_Array = null;
    private int Front = 0;
    private int Rear = 0;

    public Queue(int size) {
        Front = Rear = 0;
        Queue_Array = new Object[size];
    }

    public Queue() {
        this(100);
    }

    protected void finalizer() {
        Front = Rear = 0;
        Queue_Array = null;
    }

    final public boolean empty() {
        return Front == Rear;
    }

    final public boolean full() {
        return Rear == Queue_Array.length;
    }

    public void queueAdd(Object token) {
        if (!full()) {
            Queue_Array[Rear] = token;
            Rear++;
        }
    }

    public Object queueDelete() {
        Object Value_return = -999;
        if (!empty()) {
            Value_return = Queue_Array[Front];
            Front++;
            return Value_return;
        }
        return Value_return;
    }
}//end of Class_Queue

public class ClassQueue {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int i = 0;
        String Value_1 = "ABBA";


        Stack Value_1_Stack = new Stack(Value_1.length());
        Queue Value_1_Queue = new Queue(Value_1.length());


        while (i < Value_1.length()) {
            Value_1_Stack.push(Value_1.charAt(i));
            Value_1_Queue.queueAdd(Value_1.charAt(i));
        }

        i = 0;

        while (Value_1_Stack.pop() == Value_1_Queue.queueDelete()) {
            i++;
        }

        if (i == Value_1.length()) {
            System.out.println("Palindrome");
        } else {
            System.out.println("NOT");
        }


    }//end of main
}//end of ClassQueue
```

Comment: can you please show the error?

Comment: do u have to use stack and queue? or whatever is the easiest?

Comment: I have to use :s
I can't Debug, had no clue where the error is :s

Comment: @umar: you state you "can't debug". But why? Do you have a religious proscription against debugging? You could have solved your problem easily by sprinkling your code with println statements or by using one of the many free debuggers available, but you state that for some reason you're not allowed to that? I've never heard of such a thing.

Comment: God.. Racism everywhere.. anyways am not gonna respond to that really.. I used the netbeans debugger and the eclipse one also but those two stuck at some point dunno why.. am not new to debuggers as am a professional in C and C++;
Tried to make a println statment but that didn't work too I wasn't solvin the infinite loop;

Comment: Racism? Really? You've got to be kidding. Sarcasm at crazy statements such as "I can't debug" is not racist. The solution is easy: learn to debug.

Comment: But Sarcasm using religions is considered Racism for some people :) about your second statement.. I've already answered that :)

Comment: @Umar: I have no idea what religion you profess, and I really don't care. I tolerate and respect **all** religions, but on the same token I am equally intolerant of statements such as "I can't debug". If you have trouble debugging, you show your effort and explain your troubles rather than make statements that make no sense other than to suggest that you're not trying hard enough (or at least not demonstrating your efforts).

Comment: mate.. I've traced the code on paper for like 2 hours because the debugger wasn't running and I was increminting the value each time not getting there wasn't an i++ statment .. and Until now the debugger isn't working.. My CPU gets to 80C and nothin really happens :s I know I have to find the answer myself and that what I tell everyone that asks me for help without giving an effort.. I edited "I can't debug" :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've got an infinite loop here as `i` is never incremented:

```
while (i < Value_1.length()) {
   Value_1_Stack.push(Value_1.charAt(i));
   Value_1_Queue.queueAdd(Value_1.charAt(i));
}
```

Also don't exceed the length of the `String` `Value_1`:

```
while (i < Value_1.length() - 1) {
   Value_1_Stack.push(Value_1.charAt(i));
   Value_1_Queue.queueAdd(Value_1.charAt(i));
   i++;
}
```

Aside: Use Java naming conventions for variable names.

Comment: No worries, learn to use the debugger in eclipse by setting breakpoints. It's useful for finding these types of issues

Answer (score -1):

You cannot create class with the name of package name.

To run your program 
change the package name.

For ClassQueue create another ClassQueue.java file in same package.

To Debug program: Run>Debug

This will give you environment for debugging
Change view: Window>Show View>Debug